# jQuery.html() being garbled in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, character-encoding, keycode

I am using `jQuery("#shipdata").html()` function to get the html content of the element, which should return a date string, such as '5/14/2014'. It runs perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. But in Internet Explorer, it returns something strange:

I tried to alert the length of the returned string and it says "14", which should be "9".

Also I tried to alert the keycode of each character, and found that a keycode of "8206" is being added not only at the beginning of the string, but also before and after the character '/'.

How can I get rid of those garbled characters?

Comment: can u create jsfiddle for same

Comment: Have you tried instead: `jQuery("#shipdata").text()` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried .text() also. But still not working.

Comment: So please consider to provide a jsFiddle where your issue is replicated. BTW, which IE version?

Comment: Show what console.log($("#shipdata").html() shows, also show html markup

Comment: Character 8206 is the Unicode [left-to-right mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm). What kind of element is `#shipdata`? A `<textarea>`, by any chance?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9K29r/. I cannot reproduce the problem with jsfiddle, but I just get an idea why it is happened. Because the date is generated by PHP, I am thinking the problem may happen on the server side script.

Comment: #shipdate is a span element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character 8206, or `\u200E`, it the "left-to-right mark" character. It is used primarily in bidirectional text to indicate that "this part" should be left-to-right.

Depending on the locale, IE may be inserting these marks to ensure that the date is rendered correctly. For instance, if you are on a computer that is set to a right-to-left language, then it may be using these marks to assist in rendering.

While I don't know what's causing it, you should probably be sanitising the input anyway, for example in case of spaces.

```
<div id="shipdata">
    5/12/2014
</div>
```

The above would cause your code to fail too. So, try this:

```
jQuery('#shipdata').html().replace(/[^0-9\/]/g,'');
```

Comment: Yes, that works!! I looked into the code and find that the #shipdate is updated by the javascript function date.toLocaleDateString(), which causes the problem in IE. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: In case anyone's wondering "how the hell do you know that", I use `\u200E` as a delimiter when user data can be in the middle of a string, to prevent layout "hacks" - harmless tricks that result in unexpected ordering of symbols.

Comment: Use `unicode-bidi: isolate` or `isolate-override` for user input if appropriate. =)

Comment: @minitech Ooh, nice one. But I'm gonna stick with `\u200E` because it has the extra property of being an extra character, and with the colour code system in this project, a trailing backtick would escape the system-added "colour reset" code and cause a problem, and oh crap I just realised my project doesn't have any way to end unclosed bold/italic things...

Answer (score 0):

By using a small piece of jquery code you can achieve the result. CHECK the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T2Ws5/1/)**.

**jquery code**

```
alert($("#shipdata").html());
alert($("#shipdata").html().length);
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="shipdata">5/12/2014</div>
```